# Laradock mysqldump not found when executing artisan backup:run (Spatie Laravel Backup)

Tags: laravel, laradock, mysql-backup, laravel-backup

I have deployed a Laravel application with Laradock.

*I want to point out that the database connection works fine (users can register, login, ... etc.).*

In order to back up the application, I have installed the [Spatie's Laravel Backup package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup).

I set up all config variables accordingly as follows:

**config/backup.php**

```
<?php

return [

    'backup' => [

        /*
         * The name of this application. You can use this name to monitor
         * the backups.
         */
        'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'laravel-backup'),

        'source' => [

            /*......*/

            /*
             * The names of the connections to the databases that should be backed up
             * MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite and Mongo databases are supported.
             *
             * The content of the database dump may be customized for each connection
             * by adding a 'dump' key to the connection settings in config/database.php.
             * E.g.
             * 'mysql' => [
             *       ...
             *      'dump' => [
             *           'excludeTables' => [
             *                'table_to_exclude_from_backup',
             *                'another_table_to_exclude'
             *            ]
             *       ],
             * ],
             *
             * If you are using only InnoDB tables on a MySQL server, you can
             * also supply the useSingleTransaction option to avoid table locking.
             *
             * E.g.
             * 'mysql' => [
             *       ...
             *      'dump' => [
             *           'useSingleTransaction' => true,
             *       ],
             * ],
             *
             * For a complete list of available customization options, see https://github.com/spatie/db-dumper
             */
            'databases' => [
                'mysql',
            ],
        ],

        /*
         * The database dump can be compressed to decrease diskspace usage.
         *
         * Out of the box Laravel-backup supplies
         * Spatie\DbDumper\Compressors\GzipCompressor::class.
         *
         * You can also create custom compressor. More info on that here:
         * https://github.com/spatie/db-dumper#using-compression
         *
         * If you do not want any compressor at all, set it to null.
         */
        'database_dump_compressor' => null,

        /*....*/
        ],
    ],

];
```

In Laravel Homestead the backup works fine.

`$ php artisan backup:run`.

According [to this package's docs](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-backup/v6/installation-and-setup#dumping-the-database), we need to specify the path to the `mysqldump` binaries as follows:

**config/database.php**

```
//config/database.php
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql'
        ...,
        'dump' => [
           'dump_binary_path' => '/path/to/the/binary', // only the path, so without `mysqldump` or `pg_dump`
           'use_single_transaction',
           'timeout' => 60 * 5, // 5 minute timeout
           'exclude_tables' => ['table1', 'table2'],
           'add_extra_option' => '--optionname=optionvalue',
        ]  
    ],
```

This is what I got by default in that same file:

```
            'mysql' => [
                'driver' => 'mysql',
                'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
                'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
                'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
                'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
                'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
                'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
                'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
                'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
                'prefix' => '',
                'prefix_indexes' => true,
                'strict' => true,
                'engine' => null,
                'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
                ]) : [],
                'dump'=>[
                   'dump_binary_path' => env('DB_DUMP_PATH'), // only the path, so without `mysqldump` or `pg_dump`
                   'use_single_transaction',
                   'timeout' => 60 * 5, // 5 minute timeout
                   //'exclude_tables' => ['table1', 'table2'],
                   //'add_extra_option' => '--optionname=optionvalue',
                   'add_extra_option'  => '--host='.env('DB_HOST'), 
                ]
            ],
```

In my **.env** file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DUMP_PATH='/usr/bin/'
```

If I execute the `mysqldump` inside the MySQL container, it does work:

```
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
For more options, use mysqldump --help
```

However, If I run the backup command inside the workspace container,

`artisan backup:run`

I get the error:

> Backup failed because: The dump process failed with exitcode 127 :
> Command not found : sh: 1: mysqldump: not found

Then how do I tell Laradock where the mysqldump binary path is located?

Is there a workaround? Maybe setting up a new container that connects the `Workspace` with the `MySQL` container?

Any alternative approach?

**SOLVING with the help of Adrien**
Right at the `.env` file, I indeed found that the following variable is set to false:

```
### WORKSPACE #############################################
####
# ...
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT=false
# ...
```

So i changed that to true:

```
### WORKSPACE #############################################
####
# ...
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT=true
# ...
```

I saved and exited.

This also means that I don't have to make any more changes in the `docker-compose.custom.yml` file

To apply that change, I executed (without having to stop any container)

```
$ docker-compose build workspace

$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.custom.yml up -d workspace
```

Then I got inside the container

```
$ docker exec -it my_workspace bash
```

Once inside I looked for mysqldump:

```
# which mysqldump
/usr/bin/mysqldump
```

Finally I could execute the Spatie's Laravel Backup package:

```
# artisan backup:run
Starting backup...
Dumping database xyz...
Determining files to backup...
Zipping x files and directories...
Created zip containing x files and directories. Size is x.x MB
Copying zip to disk named backMeUp...
Successfully copied zip to disk named backMeUp.
Backup completed!
```

And that did the trick!

### Further Issue

That exact same error

```bash
The dump process failed with exitcode 127 : Command not found : sh: /usr/bin/mysqldump: not found
```

shows up when trying to run

```bash
artisan backup:run
```

from a Laravel scheduled task. That means that the `php-worker` container does not have the `mysql-client` (therefore, the `mysqldump`) package installed.

**Workaround**
I logged into the container as follows:

```bash
docker exec -it php-worker sh
```

Then I installed the mysql-client as follows:

```bash
/etc/supervisor/conf.d # apk add mysql-client
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/3) Installing mariadb-common (10.5.17-r0)
(2/3) Installing mariadb-client (10.5.17-r0)
(3/3) Installing mysql-client (10.5.17-r0)
Executing busybox-1.32.1-r3.trigger
OK: 358 MiB in 107 packages
/etc/supervisor/conf.d # which mysqldump
/usr/bin/mysqldump
/etc/supervisor/conf.d # exit
```

That seemed to do the trick?

If so, a new question arises: how to include the mysql-client right from the php-worker Dockerfile?

**Answering myself**
Well, I forgot to set to true all the variables related to "_INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53795929/292015), edit laradock `.env` file and set:

```
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT=true
```

Then run:

```
docker-compose build workspace && docker-composer up -d workspace
```

That will *update* your `workspace` container and restart it.

Connect to your container:

```
docker-compose exec workspace bash
```

You should have access to `mysqldump`:

```
root@82d8b3b3c0a0:/var/www# which mysqldump
/usr/bin/mysqldump
```

Comment: Ohhh. I overlooked that `WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT=false` from both the `.env`file and the [docs](https://laradock.io/documentation/#build-re-build-containers). You are the man! **Merci trop!** I also have updated how I solved this thanks to your help.

Comment: I also missed to set to `true` all the variables of `..._INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT=true` in all other containers used, such as the `php-worker`...

Answer (score 0):

remove **dump and everything inside it** or making it comment in **config/database.php**, then it is working fine without **dump**
like below:

```
//'dump' => [
   //    'dump_binary_path' => '/path/to/the/binary', // only the path, so //without `mysqldump` or `pg_dump`
     //  'use_single_transaction',
     //  'timeout' => 60 * 5, // 5 minute timeout
      // 'exclude_tables' => ['table1', 'table2'],
     //  'add_extra_option' => '--optionname=optionvalue',
 //   ]
```

but if you are using **xamp** server on **windows** you need to change it like below:

```
'dump' => [
            'dump_binary_path' => 'C:/xampp/mysql/bin/', // only the path, so without `mysqldump` or `pg_dump`
            'use_single_transaction',
            'timeout' => 60 * 5, // 5 minute timeout
         ],
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).